# htaccess Redirection for mass links on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I had to change my Wordpress installation to accept bi-lingual content.
The old URL I was using for posts, where the blog was used only in Italian is:
www.example.com/category/post-name

and the new URL:
English:
www.example.com/post-name

Italian:
it.example.com/post-name

I am redirecting each URL as follow:
Redirect 301 /category/post-name it.example.com/post-name

Is there any solution to redirect all links from old form to new form, without the need to redirect each link separately?

Comment: `category` is a dynamic or static value ?

Comment: It is dynamic through Wordpress

Comment: Do you have other urls like `/foo/bar` (with 2 arguments, one subdirectory) that have nothing to do with categories and post name ?

Comment: No, it is only one category and then the post name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your comment into consideration, you can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder) **after** `RewriteEngine On` (or `RewriteBase`, if present) directive

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^/]+)$ http://it.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it would be better to do it with a WordPress plugin to detect if it's a category (with post name) url (more reliable).

Or you can still use a rule for each url but this is painful

Comment: +1 it should work but rule can be: `RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^/]+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: @anubhava I think OP is trying to redirect all `www` category/post-name to `it` post-name equivalent. I might be wrong i don't know

Comment: Yes it's not clear how a URL will determine English vs Italian.

Comment: I was thinking if there is a way in .htaccess code that can get that the url contains two "/" one after the domain and one after the category name, and only in this case the url will be redirected to it.example.com

Comment: Based on your comment and your initial question, i think my answer is fine for what you wanted